# Peltier inquiry

Tags: temperature, peltier, cooling

With availability for high powered Peltier thermoelectric heating / cooling I'm inclined in a cooling design incorporating them. Being first time incorporating the same I'd like more understanding and clarification unto their attributes

1. What happens when cold side temperature exceeds hot sides?
2. Are Peltier polarity reversible?
3. What fundamental equations are applicable to all Peltiers for temperature determination
4. Popular freeware softwares for calculations

Myself has never worked Peltiers.

Answer (score 2):

> With availability for high powered Peltier thermoelectric heating /
>   cooling I'm inclined in a cooling design incorporating them. Being
>   first time incorporating the same I'd like more understanding and
>   clarification unto their attributes

Google is your friend. There are any number of good articles online.

> What happens when cold side temperature exceeds hot sides?

Nothing much, although that's not encountered in operation, and pretty much implies that the TEC is not operating.

> Are Peltier polarity reversible?

Absolutely, in which case they become heaters.

> What fundamental equations are applicable to all Peltiers for
>   temperature determination

Do some research.

> Popular freeware softwares for calculations

Nope. Again, do some research. Start with manufacturers' data sheets.